# knockout observable updating in console but not binding

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I can't seem to determine the problem with this code and I'm thrashing. Hopefully someone with better Javascript chops can see what i'm doing wrong. Chrome console shows the value updating every second but it just won't bind in the view. I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PLSMW/7/

the html binding is simply:

The js file:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.BigDay = new Date("03 Jun 2013, 14:30:00");
    self.msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    self.countdown = ko.observable("24:00:00:00");

    self.tick = function () {

        var today = new Date();
        var timeLeft = (self.BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());

        var e_daysLeft = timeLeft / self.msPerDay;
        var daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

        var e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft) * 24;
        var hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);

        var e_minsLeft = (e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft) * 60;
        var minsLeft = Math.floor(e_minsLeft);

        var e_secsLeft = (e_minsLeft - minsLeft) * 60;
        var secsLeft = Math.floor(e_secsLeft);
        self.countdown = daysLeft + " : " + hrsLeft + " : " + minsLeft + " : " + secsLeft;
        console.log(self.countdown);
    };
    setInterval(self.tick, 1000);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the html bind code is:  <div data-bind="text: countdown"></div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An observable is a `function`, so you can't set it directly to the updated value. Instead, you have to invoke it:

```
self.countdown(daysLeft + " : " + hrsLeft + " : " + minsLeft + " : " + secsLeft);
```

And to show it in the console you should do

```
console.log(self.countdown());
```

Comment: I'm an idiot and it's late. I know it's a function and it was staring me right in the face. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You should look at Knockout computable http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html